# Active Directory location empty

Tags: active-directory, printer

I have defined many sites in Active Directory Sites & Services and activated the Printer Location Tracking with a GPO.

When browsing to select a location to assign a printer to or when searching in AD for printers in specific location, the sites are empty !

[image: Capture3.png]

Only one site has a domain controller.

From a gpresult /R /scope computer, all servers recognize the site to which they belong to.

Any idea ?

Thank you

EDIT :

GPO for the PLT already exists and has been linked to the domain level

As said, DC are present on one site only but this is not an issue :
[image: Sans titre.png]

My printers are all shared and published in Active Directory.

[image: Sans titre3.png]

I have to set the location manualy because i can't browse to specify a site :

[image: Sans titre2.png]

Still the AD search filter on site works

[image: Sans titre4.png]

The problem is not the PLT but the sites configuration I guess.

Comment: On the print you haven't expanded the "Servers" container. Just to be sure, have you expanded it? Could you update the print to avoid confusion please?

Comment: Do you have values assigned to the `Location` properties of your subnets? Those are what poluate the browse tree. They are generally slash delimited strings: Example: Country/State/City/etc, US/California/SanFrancisco/Building/Floor

Answer (score 1):

The GPO setting for printer locations is: 
Computer Settings / Administrative Templates / Printers / Pre-populate printer search location text
That setting does only what it says it does. It pre-populates the the location field in the printer search dialog. There several are other manual steps you need to take:

1. Enable printer publishing on your print servers
2. Assign location values to your subnet objects
3. Assign location values to each printer object

When those values are assigned, the search tool helps users find printers that have the same location string that is assigned to the subnet their workstation is located on.

Answer (score 1):

There is a checkbox on the Sharing tab:

[image]

Comment: Craig620 is the man ! The location of the subnet must be filled in. Thanks again Craig!